# Fade background color on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to fade (in || out on hover) the background image and have the active state in a CSS class, my menu looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="menuitem" id="myTag">                    
        <a href="#" class="menu-item-a">
           <span class="menu-item-span">MenuItem</span>
        </a>                   
    </li>
    <li class="menuitem" id="myTag">                    
        <a href="#" class="menu-item-a">
           <span class="menu-item-span">MenuItem 1</span>
        </a>                   
    </li>
    <li class="menuitem" id="myTag">                    
        <a href="#" class="menu-item-a">
           <span class="menu-item-span">MenuItem 1</span>
        </a>                   
    </li>
</ul>
```

Note: At the moment I have two background images (right side and left side), in order for the menu item to be expandable.

For now I want to avoid CSS3 because of browser compatibility :|

Any solution?

Comment: Make a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net) from it with what you have currently because it's not clear. Also the id attribute is unique, please use different ID-s for each item.

Comment: Use jquery delay, as soon as mouse out from your submenu apply delay and hide that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previous stated i think it's important you make a jsFiddle, or similar of any problems you're having just to make the process of helping quicker. I've put together a little something that i think you are trying to achieve but i could be wrong.

Here you could changed where I've just used background colors, to your images and have the span fade in a hover state and another image for the .active state which the script applies on clicking one of the items.

Hope this helps:

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/visualdecree/SvjHx/

Answer (score 1):

As @SoonDead mentions in his comment, it's a little hard to understand what you're saying.

But you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to change class/apperance, and lots of other things based upon a rule, such as hover.

I've created a basic example using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wigster/VTy2z/), although if you want this basic, just use the CSS `:hover` selector, ie. `span:hover{//add styling here}`